# UK Shares in Gold?

Tags: investing, gold, starting-out-investing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Investing in gold without holding physical gold](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/10241/investing-in-gold-without-holding-physical-gold)

Instead of buying actual gold, bringing it into your house, then worrying about it getting stolen.  Is it possible to buy shares in gold?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Investing in gold without holding physical gold](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/10241/4557).

Comment: you gold then you own it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ETFs are a safer version oh holding gold awithout all the headache of getting robbed.
[ETFs traded in LSE](http://www.etfsecurities.com/disclaimer_etg_en.asp).  [One more from LSE](http://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/prices-and-markets/ETPs/company-summary.html?fourWayKey=GB00B15KXX56JEUSDETCS)